# About user input buffered reader in Java

Tags: java, function, user-input, bufferedreader

so my professor told us how to use function sorry we are only at the basics it work but my problem is she didnt told us how to use users input using buffered reader if anyone know please kindly help me i will post my code below thank you
the error on command promp[ is poiting br so i guess i need to declare br on Num function but i dont know how

```
import java.io.*;
public class NegaPos{

  static BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    static void Num(float x){
        System.out.print("\n Enter number:");
    try {
          x = Float.parseFloat(br.readLine());
      } catch (IOException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
      }

}

static void E(float x){
         if(x <0){
             System.out.print(x+ " Negative");
            }
        else{
            System.out.print(x+ " Positive");      
            }      
 }

public static void main(String [] args)throws IOException{


float x;

}
}
```

Comment: The first thing I learned at university was to make sure our code and text was formatted well.

Comment: @Jan Raleight.

It annoyed me allot so I formatted the text. 
Made the bufferedreader static and added a try catch block in the NUM function.

Now please try to rephrase the question as to what you want to achieve!

Comment: One of the they taught me in primary school was how to do punctuation.  Your text makes my brain hurt!

Answer (score 0):

Changes required in you program are

1 Declare `br` as global

```
public class NegaPos {
  static BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

2 Surround `br.readLine()` in try catch

```
try {
          x = Float.parseFloat(br.readLine());
      } catch (IOException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
      }
```

Comment: hello i tried what you said.here is the code but it compiled but nothing appeared when i tried to run it.